# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 preflight OPTION call error

Tags: woocommerce, ionic3, preflight

I'm working with Ionic 3 framework project and have encountered one error whenever i m trying to send my data to the server by `POST` method (as `postAsync`), this is related to the OPTION call as the error says:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

I don't know how to solve this error, as I have added `CORS` extension to my browser, still I'm facing this error issue.

1. Is there any solution to solve this issue from browser side like from chrome devtools as i can filter it from network by `-mode:OPTIONS` but at console I'm having the same error.
2. If this not possible, then how to solve this error ?

Code:

```
this.WooCommerce.postAsync('customers', customerData).then( (data) => {...}
```

More error messages:

> polyfills.js:3 OPTIONS tusharstar.freesite.host/wc-api/v3/…... 401
>   (Unauthorized) (anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3 ... (index):1 Failed to
>   load tusharstar.freesite.host/wc-api/v3/…) Response for preflight has
>   invalid HTTP status code 401 bluebird.js:1545 Unhandled rejection
>   TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Ionic 3 with woocommerce, so my code is like this,  "this.WooCommerce.postAsync('customers', customerData).then( (data) => {...}"   Now whenever i try to post the data to the server by clicking on the button, I get this error. I have added CORS extension in my chrome browser and again postman extension too.

Comment: @nkr Just to add the detail error that I'm getting is as,
' polyfills.js:3 
OPTIONS http://tusharstar.freesite.host/wc-api/v3/customers?oauth_consumer_key=... 401 (Unauthorized)
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
...
(index):1 
Failed to load http://tusharstar.freesite.host/wc-api/v3/customers?oauth_consumer_key=...)
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
bluebird.js:1545 
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Failed to fetch  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling a lot and i really mean a lot, the answer to my 1st point is yes! It is all about the web security issue/precaution which lets the developer get the error/precaution point of OPTION call with chrome browser. Simple way to solve the problem (just for development purpose) is to disable web security for browser, restart chrome with new extension of disabled web security .exe and everything will work fine. Steps for windows user:
1.Close chrome.
2.Open cmd
3.add this code:
C:/Program File/Google/Chrome/Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"

Answer (score 0):

You can get through this very easy! Let's follow me right now

1. Create a shortcut on your desktop
   [image]
2. Right-click on the shortcut and click Properties
   [image]
3. Edit the Target property

[image]

4. Set it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --5. disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:/ChromeDevSession"
   [image]
5. In VIsual Studio Code, run ionic serve -l
   [image]
6. You're gonna see new tab open http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab. You should be aware that this link is opened in the normal chrome tab, not the "disable-web-security" chrome we have set up.
   [image]
7. Double click to the shortcut that we have set up to open the "disable-web-security" chrome tab. Then paste http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab into this tab.
   [image]

So the reason that we get multiple errors when working with woo-commerce-api is this "web-security" by Google. Then you just disable it and you actually don't need any CORS Extensions. So remove them right now if you have installed.

And this solution i write for people who learn this course https://www.udemy.com/ionic-3-apps-for-woocommerce-build-an-ecommerce-mobile-app/. This is an ionic e-commerce app that using woo-commerce-api to set and get data from Wordpress (local or live server). If you have trouble in other language not ionic, it still works fine.

Actually i have done a lot of searchings on Google to find this solution. I hope this helps all of you. Now, i need to go to bed because tomorrow i have a final report about this ionic project with my lecturer

See ya!
Quy Le

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding some lines of code in the top of .htaccess file of my WordPress root path (C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress)

Add this code in the top of your .htaccess file :

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $l [R=200,L]
```